# Datadog failing query validations...need some assistance

Tags: terraform, datadog

I am using terraform to formulate my dashboards in Datadog, for the agent uptime I am running the code chunk:

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "datadog_agent_up"{
  name = "Datadog agent status"
  type = "service check"
  
  message = "Checking health status. Notify: myemail@abc.com.my"
  
  query = "datadog.agent.up.over(env:dev,env:prod).by(instance).last(0).count_by_status()"
  
  

 monitor_thresholds{
  warning = 2
  critical = 1 
 }

 include_tags = false
 
}
```

however I still get the following validation errors:

```
Error: error validating monitor from https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitor/validate: 400 Bad Request: {"errors":["The value provided for parameter 'query' is invalid"]}
```

I've tried playing with the query type and parameters, but still same output.
I've been following this resources:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/monitors/#
Hoping some gurus out there can shed some much needed insights.
Also is there a method to dry run a query in verbose mode?

Comment: I don't have access to a DD console at the moment so I can't test that query.
What I used to do with complex queries is to write them on datadog's dashboard and then export as JSON. You'll get a JSON output from which you can copy paste it to TF. Not the best, but might work for you.

Comment: This worked, at least I have a pre-validated query before anything. Only cons is you manually create a monitor first, an extra layer of tasks I don't mind at all! Thank you so much.